# Why does the A-Sky element show up in Firefox, but not in Chrome (A-Frame)

Tags: firefox, aframe, webvr

I have a A-Sky image that appears fine in Firefox, but doesn't appear in Chrome.

All other images work fine across both browsers, so not sure why this problem is occurring.

Github: https://github.com/ybinstock/OzymandiasWebVR
Github Pages: https://ybinstock.github.io/OzymandiasWebVR/

```
   <a-scene>
      <a-camera wasd-controls-enabled="false"></a-camera>
      <a-mountain color="#F8981E"></a-mountain>
      <a-sky src="desert.jpg" rotation="0 0 0"></a-sky>
      <a-image id="trader" src="trader.jpg">
        <a-animation attribute="position" from="0 2 -20" to="0 2 -1" dur="5000"
          ></a-animation>
        <a-animation attribute="material.opacity" begin="fade" to="0"></a-animation>

      </a-image>
      <a-image id="legs" src="legs1.jpg" position="4 2 -4" material="opacity: 0">
        <a-animation attribute="material.opacity" begin="fade" to=".8"></a-animation>

      </a-image>

      <a-image id="head" src="head1.jpg" position="-2 0 -4" rotation="0 0 90"  material="opacity: 0">
        <a-animation attribute="material.opacity" begin="fade" to=".8"></a-animation>
      </a-image>

      <a-image id="text" src="text.png"  position="0 1.5 -1"  material="opacity: 0">
        <a-animation attribute="material.opacity" begin="fade" to="1"></a-animation>
      </a-image>


      <a-entity id="poem" geometry="primitive: plane" visible="false" material="color: blue"
                sound="src: url(poetry2.mp3); volume: 3; autoplay: true; loop: false"></a-entity>
      <a-entity id="wind" geometry="primitive: plane" visible="false" material="color: blue"
                sound="src: url(wind2.mp3); volume: 3; autoplay: true; loop: true"></a-entity>

    </a-scene>
```

Answer (score 2):

The image is huge and taking time to load. 13000x6500 pixels. Try resizing it down.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Comment: I had this problem too—the content was cached on my dev machine, but it took a full three minutes to load on my phone. Didn't realise 'til I used the remote profiling tools in Chrome >_>